# Copy POJO content from one bean to another

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have few Pojos in different packages, each POJO contains set of the another pojo from the same package. I need to copy all items with the same name from Package B Pojos to objects in Package A.

Eaxmple:

```
package com.vanilla.packageA;

public class Student{

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Set<Course> course;

    //getters and setters ommited

}
```

---

```
package com.vanilla.packageA;

    public class Course{
    private String courseName;
    private String courseDescription;

    //seters and getters
}
```

---

```
package com.vanilla.packageB;

public class Student{

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Address address;
    private Set<Course> course;
    Private Date birtday;

    //getters and setters ommited

}
```

---

```
package com.vanilla.packageB;

public class Course{
    private String courseName;
    private String courseDescription;
    private <Lecturer> lecturer;
    private Integer hours;

    //seters and getters
}
```

I want to copy recursively all items from `PackageB` classes to `packageA` classes which exists in `PaCkageB` and shares the same name.

Updates:

Guys, I understand that that this is stupid question, but I need to maintain this code, now the code is written in the way that they have to call 50 getters and setter, or calling constructor with 50 parameters. 
Unfortunately,  I can't use the same object and I need to copy it, but I must find more "elegant" way to copy tese beans.

Comment: Seems like a strange request. Do you need to access protected or default methods/variables?

Comment: I have getters and setters, so I can use it.

Comment: I would say you have either a POJO or a Bean. "POJO is an acronym for Plain Old Java Object. The name is used to emphasize that a given object is an ordinary Java Object, not a special object, and in particular not an Enterprise JavaBean. " from the wikipedia entry of POJO

Comment: If you don't need access to package scope stuff, then why not just use the classes from package B? There's no reason why you need the classes to be in package A.

Comment: Please see my update it will explain more.

Comment: @danny - Still don't understand. Are you saying that the classes in package B are too complicated and you don't need all the 50 fields? If there is a default constructor (required by beans standards) then you can simply ignore the ones you don't require.

Comment: @Qwerky, You are right but If these classes has 40 items in common, I don't want to call setters and getters 40 times.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Any reason why Apache [BeanUtils.copyProperties](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) does not work?

Comment: Will apache BeanUtils copy items from different class? I always used it to copy the same pojos of the same class.

Comment: Actually it does work, provided both class have identical getters and setters.

Comment: BeanUtils won't do deep copy, though. So nested beans etc won't work (bizarrely).

Comment: Beanutils has third party issue, do you know other alternative?

Answer (score 6):

Well.. [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) may be just the thing you're looking for.

. . .  its an object to object mapping framework. The idea is that:

- Usually it will map by convention.
- You can override this convention with a mapping file.

. . therefore mapping files are as compact as possible. Its useful for many cases, such as mapping a use-case specify service payload on to the reusable core model objects.

When delivering the SpringSource training courses we used to point out this framework very often.

Answer (score 5):

See to [mapstruct](http://mapstruct.org/). This tools generates code, so there is no overhead on reflection.

Answer (score 3):

If you already have spring dependencies you could use `org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils`

```
BeanUtils.copyProperties(from, to);
```

Comment: what if my attributes are in different cases ,any option?

Answer (score 1):

Copying fields values are a need I almost every project, for example for do the clone(). I also think that for accomplish some goals isn't necessary import .jars for using only one function. I would like share some little code in which I was working, there are some things that I left in the inkwell but in general it do the work. In this case I use reflection.

```
public class ObjectCopyTools {

static String[] bases = new String[] {"byte", "short", "int", "long", "float", "double", "char", "boolean"};
static String[] equivalents = new String[] {"Byte", "Short", "Integer", "Long", "Float", "Double", "Character", "Boolean"};

static {

}

private static boolean areEquivalents(String type1, String type2){
    for (int i = 0; i < bases.length; i++) {
        if((type1.equals(bases[i]) && type2.equals(equivalents[i])) 
                || (type2.equals(bases[i]) && type1.equals(equivalents[i]))){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static <T extends Object, Y extends Object> Y deepReflectionObjectCopy(T origin, Class<Y> resultClass) {
    Class<? extends Object> origClass = origin.getClass();
    Y resultObject = null;
    for (Constructor<?> constructor : resultClass.getConstructors()) {
        if (constructor.getParameterCount() == 0) {
            try {
                resultObject = (Y) constructor.newInstance();
            }catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    if(resultObject == null){
        return null;
    }
    Field[] origFields = origClass.getDeclaredFields();
    Field[] destFields = resultObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

    Object value = null;
    for(Field dstField: destFields){
        try {
            Field tempOrigField = origClass.getDeclaredField(dstField.getName());
            if(tempOrigField.getType().equals(dstField.getType())
                    || areEquivalents(tempOrigField.getType().getSimpleName(), dstField.getType().getSimpleName())){
                dstField.set(resultObject, tempOrigField.get(origin));
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        }
    }
    return resultObject;
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: is there any piece of code you forgot to add , this is not working - i tried but  could not find what was missing

Comment: This code works to me, and is a generic code, don't have any special or missing piece of code. Could you please be more specific about why isn't working to you?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using [BULL](https://github.com/HotelsDotCom/bull)? you can find a guide on how to use it on [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-transform-any-type-of-java-bean-with-one-li). It offers the possibility to also perform object transformation while coping.
Moreover, it performs the copy recursively and don't need getter and setters defined.

Answer (score 0):

If DRY is a bedrock principle of computer science, what reason can you give for two identical, parallel object graphs?  Not only have you doubled your maintenance burden, but now you have to develop a recursive method to do nothing but ferry data from one to the other.

Comment: Unfortunately this code was not designed by me I just maintaining it now. Currently they are using constructors with 50 parameters which they got from the other class. :)

Comment: An example being code generated by webservices. In my code I have to request an object by ID using getCustomerById() and then to update it I have to make a call to setCustomer(CustomerUpdateRequest). getCustomerId returns a CustomerResponse - all the fields inside are Strings/ints/longs, or are things like AddressResponse. The CustomerUpdateRequest contains Strings/ints/longs and AddressRequest, but all the field names are the same, ad-infinitum!

Answer (score 0):

Using PropertyUtils, you can copy onky the non null properties as follows:

```
    private void copyNonNullProperties(Object destination,
            Object source) {
        try {
            PropertyUtils.describe(source).entrySet().stream()
                    .filter(source -> source.getValue() != null)
                    .filter(source -> !source.getKey().equals("class"))
                    .forEach(source -> {
                        try {
                            PropertyUtils.setProperty(destination, source.getKey(), source.getValue());
                        } catch (Exception e22) {
                            log.error("Error setting properties : {}", e22.getMessage());
                        }
                    });

        } catch (Exception e1) {
            log.error("Error setting properties : {}", e1.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [jodd](https://github.com/oblac/jodd) library.

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jodd</groupId>
    <artifactId>jodd-bean</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Code example:

```
MyObject source = ...
MyObject target = ...
BeanCopy.beans(source, target).declared(true, true).copy();
```