# Synchronize two pojos with like-named fields together

Tags: java, automatic-properties

I have two pojos.

```
public class Pojo1 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1302290920579795856L;

    private Long id;
    private String idNumber; 
    private String vendorNumber; 
    private Date expires;

    // Getters and setters for each one
}

public class Pojo2 implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1302290920579795856L;

    private Long id;
    private String idNumber; 
    private String vendorNumber; 
    private Date expires;
    private String otherData;

    // Getters and setters for each one
}
```

Is there a Java API that I can use to create a Pojo1 from a Pojo2 automatically?

I.e.:

```
Pojo1 newPojo1 = SomeLibrary.fromPojoWithLikeNamedFields(pojo2);

// newPojo1 now has all the fields that had the same name from pojo2
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937567/copy-pojo-content-from-one-bean-to-another

Comment: You could use reflection to achieve this, invoking the setter with the value from the relevant getter...

Comment: Why do you need Pojo?. It's the same type. Even the serialVersionUID is identical.

Answer (score -1):

won't a copy constructor do the job?,

```
public Pojo1(Pojo2 pojo2){
    this.id = pojo2.getId();
    this.idNumber = pojo2.getIdNumber();
    this.vendorNumber = pojo2.getVendorNumber();
    this.expires = pojo2.getExpires();
}
```

and then use as such,

```
Pojo1 newPojo1 = new Pojo1(pojo2);
```

or am I misunderstanding something...?

Comment: +1 (sry, over my daily limit). I think the same as you. Only thing I would change is to call getters, because his attributes are private.

Comment: He doesn't want to have to write the copy constructor in the first place.

Comment: @jlordo, Excellent point, I completely overlooked that; modified code to use getters! :)

Comment: @TomG, I think including this copy constructor makes much more sense than using a third party library.

Comment: I totally agree, and did not downvote you -- just pointing out that the original question implied a generic approach to any two POJOs with similar bean properties, as I read it.

Comment: I'm downvoting this - doesn't use reflection - this serves no purpose i can already copy paste each one