# Can't Clone Model.Object when ID is AUTO INCREMENT

Tags: java, playframework, clone, ebean

I implement cloneable interface to clone my object ( copy buttons 1 or multiple Object ), however, when Id of a model is auto increment, the object.save(); does not work!
I tried many solutions on the web but no way!

1- in my model :

```
@Override
public Computer clone()
{

    try
    {
        Computer nouveau = (Computer) super.clone();
        return nouveau;
    }

    catch (CloneNotSupportedException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
public Result CopyComputers(Long selected)
{
        Computer c = Computer.find.byId(selected);
        Computer cClone = c.clone();
        Logger.debug("Object is perfectly copied and ID TOO !!!! : "+cClone);
        cClone.save(); // never works coz id is the one from primary model object.

}
```

I tried these solutions but none is working!!!
1- setting id to NULL befor save...
2- generation type as shown below

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    public Long id;
```

any one has an idea please ? because if my object has manytomany or onetomany other columns.....i cant do this each time :

```
public Result CopyComputers(String selected)
{



        //Computer cClone = c.clone();

  String[] ids = selected.split(";");

  for (String temp : ids)
  {
        Computer c = Computer.find.byId(Long.parseLong(temp));
        try
        {

            Computer n = new Computer();
            if (c != null)
            {
            n.name = c.name;
            n.status = c.status;            
            n.introduced = c.introduced;
            n.discontinued = c.discontinued;
            n.createdt = c.createdt;
            n.createby = c.createby;
            n.moddt = c.moddt;
            n.modby = c.modby;
            n.site = c.site;
            n.company = c.company;

            n.save();
            Logger.debug("zzzzzzzz : "+n.id   +" "+c.id);
            }
            //cClone.save();

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.error("Clone error", e);

        }



   Logger.info("Computer Object "+temp+" has been Copied");

   } // end for

        return GO_HOME;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to (nor should) use clone on Ebean entity beans.  Instead you can just set the id value to null and use explicit insert() like:

```
Computer c = Computer.find.byId(selected);
// null out the current id value if you are
// inserting back into the same db
c.setId(null); 

// use explicit insert. This tells Ebean to ignore the 
// state of the entity and forces a sql insert
c.insert();
```

Note that alternatively you can use `BeanState.resetForInsert()` and you may do this when the insert/save cascades to associated beans that you also are looking to copy.

That is, before the insert() is called (that will cascade to associated beans) we ought to modify those related/associated beans setting their id values to null and calling `Ebean.getBeanState(otherBean).resetForInsert()` ... thus these other related beans are also inserted.

Comment: Hello rob, i m working play framework and by testing your code in the controller ( java of course ) it says : cannot find symbol for : setId & insert()!!! Could you tell me which import package can do this please!!!

Comment: It sounds like you may be using an old version of Ebean. A couple of years ago Ebean took over the Model object from Play framework.  The current version of Ebean is 10.1.1 (but that is brand new and in io.ebean package). I suspect the dependency you have is ebean 4.x ?  Can you confirm the current Ebean version of the app?

Comment: in FOLDER : Project >> addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.1")
do i have to change this to 10.1.1 ? if yes, are you sure that mu whole project not gona be in trouble!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `clone` creates a copy of your object including all the properties, but, as stated [at the Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--):

> By convention, the object returned by this method should be independent of this object (which is being cloned). To achieve this independence, **it may be necessary to modify one or more fields of the object returned by super.clone before returning it**.

Your `save` is failing because the persistence mechanism is trying to do a `INSERT` using the existent `id` and then you get a constraints error. To solve that, just do something like this:

```
@Override
public Computer clone() {

    try {
        Computer nouveau = (Computer) super.clone();
        nouveau.id = null; // reseting the id
        return nouveau;
    }

    catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
```

Please, also be aware of the [restrictions and conventions defined by `clone` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone--).

Comment: Hi MARCOS,
I tried your solution before and this is not working...!!!
Any other idea please, FYI : i am working on play framework and trying to clone object...

Comment: Please, add the error you are seeing. What do you mean by "is not working"?

Comment: There is no error in the log file, the cloned model is not null but save method  is not working...

Comment: And again, what do you mean by not working? It is not saving the object? How are you running the application? Or is this a junit test?

Comment: it is not saving because when i log the model cloned, it kept the id of the primary model(object) even with setting it to NULL value ....
it is normal that wouldnt work because id is auto increment and the same id will never be saved :)
any idea please about cloning model object in play framework....thank you

Comment: Hum, `clone` is probably a bad idea here, specially considering that your models were enhanced and possible proxied by Ebean. A more sane approach would be to manually copy the data into a new and clean object.

Comment: Hello marco,
this is what i've done to copy manually my object, however it is too long to do it each time here is the sample that works manually : http://imgur.com/a/2KuNf 
but i really apreciate if there is something such as clone() method thank you so much marco, even WILL SARGENT from lightbend told me that it is a bad idea ^^

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937567/copy-pojo-content-from-one-bean-to-another