# How can I avoid so many if statements in copying one object to another?

Tags: java

I have the following class:

```
public class File
{
@Getter
@Setter
private String id;

@Getter
@Setter
private String name;

@Getter 
@Setter
private int size;

@Getter
@Setter
private String color;

... about 10 more variables
}
```

And I have two instances of this class:

```
File file = new File(); // assume each variable has a value initialized
File newFile = new File(); // assume each variable has a value initialized
```

The logic I want is if my `newFile` contains a value for a variable, I want to keep it. Otherwise I want to fallback to whatever my original value is in the `file` object.

So I have the following method:

```
public void merge(File oldFile, File newFile)
{
    if (newFile.getId() != null)
    {
       oldFile.setId(newFile.getId());
    }

    if (newFile.getName() != null)
    {
       oldFile.setName(newFile.getName());
    }

    if (newFile.getSize() != null)
    {
       oldFile.setSize(newFile.getSize());
    }

    if (newFile.getColor() != null)
    {
       oldFile.setColor(newFile.getColor());
    }

    ... etc
}
```

How can I avoid so many if statements and null checks? The code in my opinion looks pretty ugly.

Comment: Why do you need the null checks? If nulls are allowed, just copy the nulls.

Comment: if it's null it means I want to fallback to whatever the oldFile value is, I don't want to replace it with null. See my comment "The logic I want is if my newFile contains a value for a variable, I want to keep it. Otherwise I want to fallback to whatever my original value is in the file object."

Comment: Do you use lombok?

Comment: @sc0der yes, I also am looking into a library called ModelMapper, I'm wondering if that will be useful here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy POJO content from one bean to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937567/copy-pojo-content-from-one-bean-to-another)

Comment: "*null it means I want to fallback to whatever the oldFile value is*" - consider using `Optional` for this purpose instead of `null`. In addition to being more semantically meaningful and type-safe, `Optional` has many useful helper methods that may save you some boilerplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function that defaults to the old value if the new value is null - or you can use a prewritten one like :
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ObjectUtils.html#defaultIfNull(T,%20T)

This means your code becomes :

```
public void merge(File oldFile, File newFile)
{
   oldFile.setId(defaultIfNull(newFile.getId(), oldFile.getId());

   oldFile.setName(defaultIfNull(newFile.getName(), oldFile.getName());

   oldFile.setSize(defaultIfNull(newFile.getSize(), oldFile.getSize());

   // etc
```

}

Of course, if you decide this behaviour should ALWAYS be the case for your files, then you could put this in all the setters instead, like :

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = defaultIfNull(name, this.name);
}
```

Then just call as normal :

```
public void merge(File oldFile, File newFile)
{
   oldFile.setId(newFile.getId());

   oldFile.setName(newFile.getName());

    // etc
}
```

Comment: the defaultIfNull is not bad... I just think it's a bit weird to fallback and call a setter with the same value it's already set as if the new value is null, I would think it's better not to even call the setter then

Comment: Depends on how you define “weird” and “better” :).  IMHO I would rate both forms that I mention as “better” than the indented `if` blocks in the question, and both are also common practice that I have seen at work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `merge` function in Utility class that takes two file objects and use reflection to do this

```
    static final class FileUtil {

        private FileUtil() throws IllegalAccessException {
            throw new IllegalAccessException("can not create an object from this class!");
        }

        public final static void merge(File oldFile, File newFile) throws Exception {
            Method[] methods = newFile.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
            for (Method m : methods) {
                if (m.getName().contains("get")) {
                    Object value = m.invoke(newFile);
                    if (value != null) {
                        String name = m.getName();
                        name = name.substring(name.indexOf("get") + 3);
                        name = "set" + name;
                        if (value instanceof Integer) {
                            Method method = oldFile.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(name, int.class);
                            method.invoke(oldFile, (int) value);
                        } else {
                            Method method = oldFile.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(name, value.getClass());
                            method.invoke(oldFile, value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```