# Java Change return type of library package

Tags: java

In my Java project,
I downloaded the following package through Maven:
https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api

With this API,
I am capable of getting Candlesticks from Binance,
however;
the function:
[Get weekly candlesticks](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-java-api#weekly-candlestick-bars-for-a-symbol)
returns a `List<Candlestick>`,
but I created my own class `Candlestick` that contains everything from
their class `Candlestick`,
except mine has a few more attributes.
Now I tried the following code:

```
public static List<Candlestick> getCandlesticks(
    String symbol,
    int limit,
    LocalDateTime startLocalDateTime,
    LocalDateTime endLocalDateTime)
{
    BinanceApiClientFactory factory =
        BinanceApiClientFactory.newInstance(API_KEY, SECRET);
    BinanceApiRestClient client = factory.newRestClient();
    
    CandlestickInterval interval = CandlestickInterval.HOURLY;
    long startTime = startLocalDateTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) * 1000;
    long endTime = endLocalDateTime.toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC) * 1000;
    
    return client.getCandlestickBars(symbol, interval, limit, startTime, endTime);
}
```

But that gives me the error:
[image]

I can't edit the source file,
because it is read only,
so how can I get the function to return my `List<Candlestick>` class?

Comment: You can't.  You'll have to manually copy each item from their class to yours, filling in each attribute as you go.

Comment: It's just like that error where the required type is int and you are providing String to it.
In the same manner, your required type: and provided type is not matching.
You can always make your custom library and use that in your project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. Your CandleStick class and the library's CandleStick class are different classes. That's exactly what the error message is telling you. You will also notice that the packages of the classes are different.

You need to convert each item in the list to "adapt" the return type to your expected type. You could use the Streams API, for instance:

```java
return client.getCandlestickBars(symbol, interval, limit, startTime, endTime)
        .stream()
        .map(cs -> convertMyCandleStick(cs))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`convertMyCandleStick` will probably look something like this:

```java
private static Candlestick convertMyCandleStick(final com.binance.api.client.domain.market.Candlestick candlestick) {
    if (candlestick == null) return null;
    final Candlestick converted = new Candlestick();
    converted.setId(candlestick.getId());
    converted.setName(candlestick.getName());
    // repeat for all properties ...
    return converted;
}
```

If the properties in both classes have the same name and type, you can use [`BeanUtils#copyProperties`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#copyProperties-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-) as explained in the answers to the question [Copy POJO content from one bean to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937567/copy-pojo-content-from-one-bean-to-another).

Comment: Okay thanks, I had this as solution, but the class has 34 attributes, so I was wondering if there wasn't something I could do to prevent this solution :(

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk see my updated answer. You might be able to use `BeanUtils` of Apache commons

Comment: Pointing out `BeanUtils` has a "do it for me" option is a nice find, good answer.